# Question about pronouns: using a pronoun when the thing referred to is understood

Tags: pronouns, discourse-context

I have a question about the use of pronouns. The definition is that pronouns are used for substituting a noun or a noun phrase. But in a real-life context, the noun or noun phrase might not be mentioned verbally. If the thing is understood or is just obvious, can I use the pronoun right away?

**Example 1**

(My friends and I are at a new place. I point at a woman I don't know )

I: **She** is so stylish.

My friends: Yes, we should go and know more about **her**.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Is it impossible in your own language?

Comment: Some pronouns rarely have referents. For example: "**Anyone** can go there."

Comment: The definition you give is correct. It says nothing about having to say the noun phrase before. If it's understood, just use it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a normal and typical use of pronouns.

There is no need to mention the referent before the use of the pronoun. You and use the wider context or body language.